# Unexpected patterns in cumulative data R

Tags: r

I've got some data that I've calculated cumulative proportions and standard deviations for, and when I plot it I'm seeing some patterns I wasn't expecting. Is something wrong with my code, is there some statistical thing going on I don't understand, or do I need to look at my data collection methods?

Here's my data. It's counts of gaps of varying sizes in a pile of rocks (too small, too big, or 'good' gaps).

```
small<-c(2,2,2,4,4,8,6,1,2,3,3,2,1,4,2,1,0,2,7,3,1,6,2,7,3,4,5,2,2,2,2,3,2,7,2,1,3,4,1,1,3,1,3,4,2,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,1,3,3,0,3,2,4,1,2,2,1,4,3,2,1,3,3,2,6,2,0,3,3,4,5,1,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2,4,0,3,5,2,1,4,1,4,4,5,2,1)
big<-c(150,188,195,167,168,193,185,167,187,191,187,178,178,155,150,180,182,178,155,168,172,150,180,184,160,184,162,151,170,173,178,171,197,183,167,160,191,199,161,171,163,197,182,163,199,176,149,187,162,166,183,189,171,187,154,163,172,193,162,176,168,192,166,180,174,179,150,173,171,137,143,170,164,177,179,169,189,163,159,158,181,167,167,169,172,198,170,186,178,177,206,179,157,182,164,153,152,166,173,183)
good<-c(22,23,30,22,20,20,25,28,23,23,25,26,24,26,29,17,12,27,10,17,22,22,27,25,21,21,22,21,17,22,18,17,27,25,17,15,25,15,28,19,27,28,21,27,30,21,23,24,14,15,27,33,27,22,18,24,22,19,31,20,25,28,30,21,20,23,21,24,27,20,24,15,20,24,26,16,25,13,        20,18,25,17,33,26,24,17,21,12,23,23,24,16,21,28,22,19,19,19,18,17)
plotgaps<-data.frame(small,big,good)
```

(If the problem is with my data, here is some dummy data)

```
small <- rnorm(100, 5, 2)
big <- rnorm(100, 160, 20)
good < -rnorm(100, 25, 5)
plotgaps <- data.frame(small, big, good)
```

Here's the code I wrote to get cumulative mean proportions of 'good' gaps to overall gaps, and the cumulative standard deviations.

```
plotgaps$propgood <- (plotgaps$good / (plotgaps$good + plotgaps$big + plotgaps$small) * 100)
numrownames(plotgaps) <- (1:nrow(plotgaps))

#cumulative mean proportion good
for (i in 1:nrow(plotgaps)){
  plotgaps$cmpropgood[i] <- mean(plotgaps$propgood[1:i])
  plotgaps$cumsd[i] <- sd(plotgaps$propgood[1:i])
}
```

When I graph the cumulative mean proportions of my data, I get this:

```
plot(plotgaps$cmpropgood)
```

[image: cumulative graph]

It has that pattern of a dip around index 40 and then rising and falling again. I was expecting the numbers to fluctuate around the 'true' mean and get closer to the true mean as more data is added, but without a directional pattern like that.

When I graph the cumulative standard deviation I get this:

```
plot(plotgaps$cumsd)
```

[image: standard deviations graph]

It has those patterns of declining lines. I was expecting this to tend towards a 'true' standard deviation again without that sort of pattern.

The dummy data I made also has patterns in it I wasn't expecting.

```
plot(plotgaps$cmpropgood)
```

[image]

(a rise in the middle, not as pronounced as my real data)

```
plot(plotgaps$cumsd)
```

[image]

(line patterns again like my real data)

Can anyone help me out with what's happening here? Thank you!

Comment: not related to the question (i had a go at a brief answer), but for readability, howaboutsomespacesinyourcode?  See https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml#spacing or http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html.  (I was thinking of plotgaps$propgood<-(plotgaps$good/(plotgaps$good+plotgaps$big+plotgaps$small)*100))

Comment: Your code is not wrong although you could make it more efficient, e.g., `plotgaps$cmpropgood <- cumsum(plotgaps$propgood) / seq_along(plotgaps$propgood)`. This is a statistics question.

Comment: "What's happening here" appears to be entirely a psychological phenomenon, not a statistical one.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Peter, I've added some gaps! Thanks for the code checking @Roland.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely one for stats.stackexchange.

You should think through and perhaps articulate why this surprises you?  You might have context we don't.

We have a gradually increasing sample size.  So, presuming the values come from some kind of stationary process, the mean and standard deviation will gradually converge to the full population's value.  When there are larger values pop up in the increasing sample, they will spike both the mean and the sd away from where they are converging to.  Then the converging resumes.

If the data are *not* from a process you expect to be stationary, then I can't think of a reason for using the cumulative mean and standard deviation from the very beginning of the data to the most recent point (as opposed to, for example, a rolling window, which you could use functions from the `zoo` package to implement).

Something else to bear in mind: you are taking the averages and standard deviations of proportions.  This treats each row of your data as a new observation of equal weight, even though some rows have more observations than others.  The variance of the "good proportion" in each row will be inversely proportionate to its sample size. For rough and ready purposes it may be ok to ignore this, but an alternative approach would be to weight each row by its own sample size, so the rows with smaller variance get more weight in their contribution to the overall converging mean and standard deviation.

Comment: While writing a response to your answer I understood where I went wrong with this! I was surprised that the sd only fluctuates _upwards_ from the true sd because I was expecting it to be varying equally upwards and downwards. But when you get an outlier for the count, whether it is especially high or especially low doesn't matter, as either way will _increase_ the sd away from the real sd.

Comment: Yes, this is expected to be a stationary process, and the observations are expected to be independent. It's a simulation I'm running (each row represents a new simulation). I was hoping to use this cumulative data to figure out how many times I have to run the simulation to get an accurate estimate.

Also, thank you for the comment about the weighting! I didn't consider that.